# How to use numbers with useParams?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I want to see the data of my json but when i try to search for one with an ID, let's say "http://localhost:3001/pokemons/3", i got a 404.

I can see all my data at http://localhost:3001/pokemons.

Apparently useParams don't want me to use id as a number ?  I'm a bit confused

The error i got is : *Type '{ id: number; }' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | Record<string, string | undefined>'.
Type '{ id: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string | undefined>'.
Property 'id' is incompatible with index signature.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.*

Here is the code i'm struggling with :

```
const PokemonsDetail: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState<Pokemon | null>(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { id } = useParams<{ id: number}>();

  useEffect(() => {

    axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/pokemons/${id}`)
      .then(response => {
        const pokemonData = response.data;
        console.log(pokemonData); 

        if (pokemonData.id) {
          setPokemon(pokemonData);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('erreur', error);
      });
  }, [id]);
```

I tried to change useParams<{ id: number}>(); into string, there is no more error but it doesnt show anything on localhost

Comment: They're always strings. If you want numbers, parse the string.

Answer (score 1):

That is just how the [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params#useparams) hook is typed. The route path params are always strings.

> ```
> declare function useParams<
>   K extends string = string
> >(): Readonly<Params<K>>;
> ```

If you are specifying the `id` param so it can be destructured use either of the following:

```js
const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>();
```

```js
const { id } = useParams() as { id: string };
```

You can then pass this `id` *string* value to your GET request

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/pokemons/${id}`)
```

If you need `id` to be a number then you'll need to convert it yourself.

Example:

```js
const params = useParams<{ id: string }>();
const id = Number(params.id);
```

If you are doing some comparisons to data with numerical id properties, then I suggest keeping `id` as the string and converting the property you with to compare to a string as this covers strings ***and*** numbers.

Example:

```js
const { id } = useParams<{ id: string }>();

const item = items.find(
  item => String(item.id) === id // string to string comparison
);
```